# Inline CSS Not Working

Tags: css, button

I have CSS in a `<a>` tag.
Why is `color` not applied?

HTML:

```html
    <a href="example.com" style="
     .button {  
       color: red;  
     }
     .button:hover {
       color: blue;
     }">text</a>
```

Comment: all I know is you should definitely not have all that style inside a tag in the HTML. move that into an external CSS file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form your HTML is invalid as your `style` attribute is attempting to use pseudo classes (`:active`, `:hover`) and class selectors (`.button`). The `style` attribute can only include declaration blocks (without braces).

> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS declaration block (excluding the delimiting braces)

*CSS Style Attributes (http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/)*

A CSS declaration block is defined as:

> A declaration block starts with a left curly brace ({) and ends with the matching right curly brace (}). In between there must be a list of zero or more semicolon-separated (;) declarations.

*Syntax and basic data types (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets)*

Ideally the style rules would be moved into a separate stylesheet included in the `head` of the page but you could get away with extracting the rules into `style` tags.

```html
<style>
  .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: outset 5px #005072;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #a62152;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4326b5', endColorstr='#4326b5', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 2px #ffffff;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#ffffff, offx=1, offy=-1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .button:hover {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: outset 5px #005072;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #573bc7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a5194c', endColorstr='#a5194c', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #2fb5b1;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#2fb5b1, offx=1, offy=-1);
  }
  .button:active {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: inset 5px #005072;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #4326b5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a62152', endColorstr='#a62152', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 9px #36cfb0;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#36cfb0, offx=1, offy=-1);
  }
</style>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/danielspringermusic?sub_confirmation=1" class="button">Subscribe</a>
```

To summarise, you need to:

- Add a `style` block to your page (preferably in the `head`)
- Move the CSS code from the `style` attribute in the `a` to this `style` block
- Add `class="button"` to the `a`

Applying styles to elements is one of the fundamentals of building a web page so I would suggest that you follow some tutorials to teach yourself the basics. 
[Learning the Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn) looks like a good place to start.

Conversely, it appears that you are using Blogger. You can add custom CSS by following these steps:

> 1. Sign in on blogger.com.
> 2. Click on your blog.
> 3. On the left side of the page, click Templates > Customize > Advanced.
> 4. From here, you can change colors and fonts.
> 5. To make changes using custom CSS, click Add CSS.

*Use CSS to change your blog's format (https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/41954?hl=en)*

Comment: I had to add     -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px; 
    border-radius: 0px; to the hover and active, but other than that, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: how do I avoid the underline from showing upon hovering?

Comment: It's probably being set by another declaration in the stylesheet. Try adding `text-decoration: none;` to `:hover`.

Comment: Here is what worke for me. It looks like that's what you suggested too:

Comment: What order should I place the codes in? no matter which order I pick, an unwanted override seems to appear, but more specifically, it seems that on Chrome incognito, .button shows like .button-active.

Comment: On Chrome incognito, active replaces also .button

Comment: @DaniSpringer The order is important, although it is currently correct https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/. I would suggest creating a new question for this problem.

Comment: Or I can edit the question to "css button not displaying correctly". What do you think? @HiddenHobbes

Comment: I see! But what is a:link? Is the corresponding one here .button? And I like how that site writes that "LV and HT" refers to <a> tags..doesn't it refer to more things? At least, to a button too.

Comment: @DaniSpringer  Editing the question wouldn't be the correct course of action in this case as the current question is completely different to your new question (and has answers reflecting that). A new question with code showing your issue would definitely be the way to go.

Comment: So I should put my current code and ask why visited is overridden by active?

Comment: And if I got it, the guy below put an answer with the wrong order as per the love n hate selector thing.

Comment: @DaniSpringer `:hover` can be used on other elements, the others only work on links. In your case `.button` is a link (`a` tag), the class `button` is just a way for you to be able to select the element in CSS (it could, for example, be called `.sausages` and there would be no difference). Yup, create a new question with your current code, an explanation of your problem and what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Got it. But is :link correspondent to my .button, meaning default display? If needed I'll move to chat..

Answer (score 0):

You can not supply hover state for the button on the style attribute.
you can insert a style tag and then use the :hover pseudo selector

and about the .button class, just add another class or extend it..

something like:

```
<style>
/* Default button style */

.button {
    adding: 6px 16px;
    border: outset 5px #005072;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /*............. insert the rest here */
}


/* hover style - only stuff that should be
    overriden when hovering goes here,
    the default will still be relavent */

.button:hover {
    background: red;
}


/* new button - it will inherit the default button
   properties and override some of them */

.button.special {
    background: green;
}
</style>
<a href="#" class="button">Default button</a>
<a href="#" class="button special">Special button</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I am a beginner. Any way you can provide the resulting code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need more then that.. this is the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me (looks like what @hidden hobbes was suggesting):

```css
<style>
  .button {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: outset 5px #005072;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #a62152;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4326b5', endColorstr='#4326b5', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a62152 0%, #4326b5 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 2px #ffffff;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#ffffff, offx=1, offy=-1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: outset 5px #005072;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #573bc7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a5194c', endColorstr='#a5194c', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #573bc7 0%, #a5194c 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 3px #2fb5b1;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#2fb5b1, offx=1, offy=-1);
  }
  .button:active {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: inset 5px #005072;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    font: 18px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #4326b5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a62152', endColorstr='#a62152', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4326b5 0%, #a62152 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #d11abc, inset 0px 0px -1px #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 9px #36cfb0;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#36cfb0, offx=1, offy=-1);
  }
</style>
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/danielspringermusic?sub_confirmation=1" class="button">Subscribe</a>
```

Of course, the `target="_blank"` isn't necessary to accomplish the above, it's just if you prefer the link to open in a new tab.